# Simple but important question: How to get the value of contract's state when using Metamask?

Tags: solidity, metamask, interfaces

I'm designing an HTML file (or a user interface: UI) for my smart contract.

let's assume that my contract has a state as follows:

```
address public owner;// it is set to "0x5574Da45Ce5115055BB46c668D9982868ABd1382" when the contract's deployed
```

As we all know, to get the value of "owner" we can use the following command line in "geth":

```
myContract.owner.call({from: "0xEE42224D91492247da80724CAD937C2273f1D5ed"})
```

But the above code does not work if I use it in my HTML file (I get an error mentioned [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47366/the-metamask-web3-object-does-not-support-synchronous-methods-like-personal-newa)). It should have the following form to let Metamast work with it (might be other way too, but I'm not aware of it):

```
myContract.owner.call({from: "0xEE42224D91492247da80724CAD937C2273f1D5ed"}, function(err, result) { if(!err) 
// do something
});
```

Apparantly the value allocated to "owner" is stored in "result". **But I don't know how to get it and print it on my HTML page!**

**Question**: How to get/store the value returned by the above callback function?

---

Note that we can use console.log(result) in the above function but, in this way, the result does not still appear on the webpage and it appears in the background.

Comment: Try this comment, they used an example to show an async function returning a value. https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/8dyfyr/how_to_make_metamask_accept_promiseswait_for/dxr8f2j

Comment: This question doesn't belong here. It's about JavaScript, callbacks, and how to modify the HTML DOM. Nothing relates to Ethereum except that the value in question happens to come from a smart contract.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a MetaMask issue. The keyword to search for is "callback" in JavaScript.

You can't fetch the value or assign it syncronously, e.g.

`var balance = contract.function.call(...`

It has to be async, which means the response is expected *later*. This is why the second code example passes a function into the call. The function passed in is to run when the response comes back.

It's a big topic and I want to keep this succinct, hence the "keyword" hint.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the hint. Then how the result of a smart contract call can be shown on a webpage? How is it done in the "remix" or "myEtherWallet" for instance?

Comment: It's a big rabbit hole that will go beyond this comment format. The result gets passed into the callback function that was passed into the original function. The dialog is roughly "Do this, and when you're done, send the answer to this function." You see the function receives a result, then goes on to do something with the result.

Comment: If you haven't seen callbacks (and promises) before, expect to spend a day or so getting the hang of it.